# How to scrape all data of table using Jsoup in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

```kotlin
val url: String = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/nseloser/index.php"
val downServers = ArrayList()
val td: Element
val document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 100).get()
val element: Element = document.select("tbody").first()
for (tr in element.select("tr"))
{
    for (td in element.select("td")) {
        Log.d("abc", "DOinbackgroind: " + td.text() + " ")
        downServers.add(td.text())
    }
}
```

How to scrape all data of this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RKQ4.png) from this website https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/nseloser/index.php and then collect the data to show on Android using Kotlin?

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: the problem is this: `document.select("tbody").first()` as there are multiple `tbody` tags available & you are selecting the `first` which is not what you want. You could instead get the `table` tag first or the `bsr_table hist_tbl_hm` div class first

Comment: can you tell me how to get speciic table